# How to go about writing a script to automate a simple data entry position?

Tags: javascript, html, automation, scripting, data-entry

I'm a second year compsci major in college, with a dream of one day obtaining a data entry position that I can automate, tell no one that I automated it, and get paid to basically do nothing. Currently, I'm finding myself in a on-campus position that I believe would make for good practice, as the data entry seems very simple on the user end; I simply click the first entry in a list of classes, click the same three buttons, click the back page button three times, refresh the page, and repeat. I don't have any experience in writing scripts and have no idea what that entails, or if this is something as easy to script as I'm imagining, so I was hoping someone could provide me some starting tips and direction. Additionally, what language would be ideal for a task like this? My experience is mostly in Java, Haskell, and Python, but I believe I've heard that for manipulating websites I should go something like HTML or Javascript, though I'm not familiar with either. Is this accurate? Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: To be clear, this is a website I'm using for the position, not an excel spreadsheet or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would work best with a Python script using Selenium.

[Getting Started - Selenium Simple Usage](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)

You can automate keystrokes, clicks and other things.